# summing amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

The purpose of this lab is to find the gain voltage of op amp. I used multisim to plot it, but I get a constant voltage for Vout as appose to inverted signal. could you please have a look it and let me know to see what went wrong?
[image]

and here is what I designed . it says use the divider to obtain 5V but I I used a supply voltage of 5V instead

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your V3 battery is backwards .

Comment: @Engineer: Please don't forget to click on the "tick" mark next to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams if your problem is solved.

Comment: I dont seee anything, maybe that's because I am a new user I cannot do that !

Comment: @Engineer: It's under the vote arrows.

Comment: it says I don't have enough reputation to vote but I clicked on accept answer. thanks again